# Access a literal file in a folder with a rewrite rule

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have an issue accessing a literal file in my directory when there's a rewrite rule on it.

I have an image, `badge.gif`, in the folder `/images/badges/` however I also have a URL rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/images/badges/(.*)$ /images/badges/db_badge.php?badge=$1;
```

However in the database I have no `badge.gif` however there is a `badge.gif` in the folder `/images/badges/`.